# how to set mogodb in upstart service with authentication

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, startup, upstart, startupscript

I have created a superuser **tom** in mongodb v2.6.11 with **username** & **password** and now i want to add this at **ubuntu startup service**

on searching came to know that i have to edit below file

> this is how my `/etc/init/mongod.conf` looks

```
pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb/
    mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb/
end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
  ENABLE_MONGOD="yes"
  CONF=/etc/mongod.conf
  DAEMON=/usr/bin/mongod
  DAEMONUSER=${DAEMONUSER:-mongodb}

  if [ -f /etc/default/mongod ]; then . /etc/default/mongod; fi

  # Handle NUMA access to CPUs (SERVER-3574)
  # This verifies the existence of numactl as well as testing that the command works
  NUMACTL_ARGS="--interleave=all"
  if which numactl >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && numactl $NUMACTL_ARGS ls / >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
  then/etc/init/mongod.conf
    NUMACTL="$(which numactl) -- $NUMACTL_ARGS"
    DAEMON_OPTS=${DAEMON_OPTS:-"--config $CONF"}
  else
    NUMACTL=""
    DAEMON_OPTS="-- "${DAEMON_OPTS:-"--config $CONF"}
  fi

  if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGOD" = "xyes" ]
  then
    exec start-stop-daemon --start --chuid $DAEMONUSER --exec $NUMACTL $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
  fi
end script
```

> ### ATTEMPT 1 :by using mongo command line

```
sudo mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

but don't know what to change in `/etc/init/mongod.conf` ?

---

> ### ATTEMPT 2 :by using /etc/mongod.conf

1. Did Changes In `/etc/mongod.conf`

`auth = true`

`port = 27017`

2. `$sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`
3. `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` after firing command

   `2016-01-20T23:58:41.675+0530 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
   2016-01-20T23:58:41.677+0530 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3168 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=vijay
   2016-01-20T23:58:41.677+0530 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.11
   2016-01-20T23:58:41.677+0530 [initandlisten] git version: d00c1735675c457f75a12d530bee85421f0c5548
   2016-01-20T23:58:41.677+0530 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build4.ny.cbi.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
   2016-01-20T23:58:41.677+0530 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
   2016-01-20T23:58:41.677+0530 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
   2016-01-20T23:58:41.812+0530 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
   2016-01-20T23:58:41.812+0530 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
   2016-01-20T23:58:41.934+0530 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] got signal 2 (Interrupt), will terminate after current cmd ends
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] dbexit: 
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 10
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 13
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.746+0530 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.838+0530 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.843+0530 [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.843+0530 [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.843+0530 [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.949+0530 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
   2016-01-20T23:58:47.949+0530 [signalProcessingThread] dbexit: really exiting now`
4. **But on closing terminal mongodb also closes**

> ### ATTEMPT 3

1. Did Changes In `/etc/mongod.conf`

`auth = true`

`port = 27017`

2. **RESTART COMPUTER**
3. `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` after **RESTARTING COMPUTER**

   `2016-01-21T00:40:13.011+0530 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.014+0530 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1012 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=vijay
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.014+0530 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.11
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.014+0530 [initandlisten] git version: d00c1735675c457f75a12d530bee85421f0c5548
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.014+0530 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build4.ny.cbi.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.014+0530 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.014+0530 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.439+0530 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
   2016-01-21T00:40:13.440+0530 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now`
4. **Observation** : `Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating`
   I found this Error in log .Don't know if it causing mongodb to terminate.if it is causing mongo to **STOP** at computer start then how to set permisssion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to fiddle with the startup files (which you really should not do unless you *exactly* know what you are doing) or install additional software for managing MongoDB.

I'd rather suggest to [read MongoDB's extensive documentation of the config file options](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization).

The only thing you need to do is to set

```
auth=true
```

for legacy config files or

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

for YAML config files in `/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: @plutopunch Well, then I have to tell all my customers... And the other DBAs... And MongoDB Inc.... ;) the parameter is _exactly_ there for that purpose, please add the log output by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34861198/edit).

Comment: Instead of star int it manually, simply use `service MongoDB restart` to apply config changes.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively possible to use `supervisor`:

```
apt install supervisor
```

Setting for process mongodb:

create file `myupstartservice.conf` at location `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` and put below code

```
[program:mongo]
command=/usr/bin/mongod --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
priority=100
```

then checkservice

`service supervisor restart`

[some reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)

Comment: Why the heck should one use supervisor  on top of upstart on top of init?

Comment: It is much easier to configure, which greatly simplifies life.

Comment: And adds a moving part totally unnecessary, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34863984/1296707).

Comment: Oh, and btw: you should never, ever run MongoDB as root.

Comment: well, this is just an example ;)

Comment: Alex, forgive me, but to get it running somehow isn't the best idea. An example? Every attacker able to gain access to the MongoDB instance in question might acquire root rights at the machine if OP used the configuration you suggested. Do not assume that suggestions will be reflected. Often enough, it is just c&p. With mongod running as root, there is no 5% security margin of disk space: Your mongodb might fill the FS, making it impossible to do further administrative tasks, forcing you to run from a live system. Will it run as root via supervisor? Yes. Is it a good idea? Not so much.

Comment: ^ blah blah blah. I compiled mongo from source because new versions aren't available for Raspberry pi. Because of this, I had to make my own initialization setup. Might as well use supervisor or systemD because why use upstart?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks `@Markus W mahalberg` extending your answer in detailed steps

> ### Correct Mongodb Way to set mongo in startup with authentication

---

**Steps** :

1 : `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org`      - *in new terminal*

2 : `sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`

3 : `mongo --port 27017`      -  *in new terminal*

4 : `use admin`

5 : Lets setup [**superuser**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#superuser-roles)

```
db.createUser(
{
    user: "tom",
    pwd: "jerry",
    roles: [
              { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
              { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
              { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
              { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" }
           ]
})
```

6 : Lets configure for ***Startup service*** for that Do Changes In `/etc/mongod.conf`  and set

`auth = true`

`port = 27017`

7 : `sudo /etc/init.d/mongod stop` OR `sudo service mongod stop`    - *in new terminal*

8 : `sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start` OR `sudo service mongod start`

9 : `restart your pc` and before restarting your pc please empty this file `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` and save

> Now lets check **TWO** things **Authentication** & **mongodb running at startup**

1 :**Check Authentication setup**

`mongo --port 27017 -u "tom" -p "jerry" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`      -  *in new terminal*

**Note** : *this step is most important step .*

*it will give Output on terminal like*

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
>
```

2 :**Check if mongodb is running at startup**

### Run below command without running `mongod` as mongod should have started in startup

`mongo --port 27017 -u "tom" -p "jerry" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`      -  *in new terminal*

If it dosent start then open this file '/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log' .

### if it contains Error log :

`Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating`

Then apply these permissions and restart and again check

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/.
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
sudo /etc/init.d/mongod stop` OR `sudo service mongod stop    
sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start` OR `sudo service mongod start
```

**If it does not contains above error log then you should have successfully started mongodb at startup**

Answer (score 0):

1 : Got to ->  `$cd /etc/init/`

2 :Through vi Or nano editor Create file `myservice.conf` with below code

```
description "service to start mongodb at startup"
author "plutopunch :)"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 99 5

script
     export HOME="/home/admin"

     exec sudo mongod --port 27017 --auth --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
end script

post-start script
end script
```

3 : restart pc

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/