# Add authentication to mongod.conf file

Tags: mongodb, database

How do I add authentication to my mongod.conf file so that I don't have to specify run `mongod --auth` every time I launch the `mongod` daemon?

Comment: But the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34863984/1296707) will definetly suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/mongod.conf

Either add or look for the `security:` section
and add `authorization: enabled` below it, like so:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

save and restart the daemon without the `--auth`

Comment: Which only works for YAML config files.